# Product Definitions Ontology

Tags: rdf, ontology, owl, foaf, opendata

Does some know of an OWL ontology describing different products? I've tried to find it on http://linkeddata.org but to no avail (or maybe I am missing something)? Ideally, the ontology would be linked to [FOAF](http://xmlns.com/foaf/spec/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basics of using GoodRelations for exposing product model details is described here:

http://www.ebusiness-unibw.org/wiki/Modeling_Product_Models

Also, this illustration might be helpful:

http://wiki.goodrelations-vocabulary.org/GoodRelations_for_manufacturers

Answer (score 2):

You might find something in [GoodRelation's stuff](http://www.heppnetz.de/projects/goodrelations/).

Answer (score 2):

If you are asking for a description vocabulary, [GoodRelations](http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1) is a plausible option, as suggested by msalvadores.

If you are looking for an ontology/taxonomy of products, you may want to look at [Google's product taxonomy](http://www.google.com/support/merchants/bin/answer.py?answer=160081). The Drupal community translated that taxonomy into [XML and RDF](http://drupal.org/node/462458), dated back in May 2009.

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile there are efforts from the makers of Goodrelations for this specific problem [1] to turn *Product Classification Systems* into *Web Ontologies*. They also work with Googles Product taxonomy.
They have developed a tool [2] in python which allows you to do the transformation automatically.

[1] http://www.ebusiness-unibw.org/ontologies/pcs2owl/

[2] https://bitbucket.org/alexstolz/pcs2owl/overview